# Can't alter padding of a div when Bootstrap 4 navbar is collapsed (mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have a navbar that is fixed to the top of page.  Below it, I have the page content. The first content is a Bootstrap 4 image carousel. I'm noticing that for mobile, I need to put top-padding on the page-container (below the navbar, which contains my carousel) or else the carousel will be obscured by the navbar when it's expanded. The problem is, the same padding is there when the navbar is collapsed, leaving a bunch of white space.

**Basically, I just want the page container (beginning w/ the carousel) to always sit right below the navbar, whether it's collapsed or not.**

Snippet below (if you run at at full page it will make sense):

```css
body {
    width:auto;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family:'Gudea', sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
   background-color:#f7f7f7 !important;

}

.page-container {
    width: inherit;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow:0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

}


.navbar {
    background-color:#f7f7f7 !important;
    border-bottom:1px solid #E9E9E9;
    padding-bottom:30px;

}

.navbar.toggler.collapsed .page-container{
    background-color: blue
    
}

.container-fluid {
    background:#373737

}

.container{
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-top:25px;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;

}

.nav-item{
    text-align: right;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px

}

.nav-link{
    text-align:left;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#0c2d1c !important;
    font-weight:700;
}


.img {
    position: relative;
    width:  100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.overview {
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 0%!important;
    margin-left: 0%!important;
}

@media (max-width: 769px) {

    .page-container{
        padding-top:50vh
    }

    .nav-link:hover span{ 
    color:#f7f7f7 !important;
    background-color:#0c2d1c;
    border-radius:8px;
    padding:6px 6px 6px 6px;
    }

    .nav-link span{ 
    padding-left:6px 
    }

}

@media (min-width: 769px) {

#about { 
    color:#f7f7f7 !important;
    background-color:#0c2d1c;
    border-radius:8px;
    padding:6px 6px 6px 6px;

}

.nav-link:hover { 
    color:#f7f7f7 !important;
    background-color:#0c2d1c;
    border-radius:8px;
    padding:6px 6px 6px 6px;

}

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!--Essential items -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Mobile specifications-->
    <meta content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name=viewport>
    <!-- CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href = "css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Fonts-->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    
  <title>Website</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


</head>
    
<body>

  <!--Navigation-->

    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
      <button id="toggle" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-right" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" id="about" href="home.html"><span><strong>ABOUT</strong></span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>NEWS</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>LAB MEMBERS</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>RESEARCH</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="publications.html"><span>PUBLICATIONS</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>OPPORTUNITIES</span></a>
              </li>
          </ul>    
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="page-container">

    <!--Carousel-->

    <div id="carouselContainer" class='container-fluid'>
      <div id="carouselRow" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px">
          <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://public.boxcloud.com/api/2.0/internal_files/712659573948/versions/757342863948/representations/png_paged_2048x2048/content/1.png?access_token=1!FQaE1Ygcg_2tnoF9ePNlbE07xrS7OhNS_HMOHJju0Eo4WXolNXHYsrppoibjO5rb99-X8oI3CKmEnjTlYHdF4P00vD4iMgygADLSSMChGqRrIld3D-2VjFxckPC5BbmQ-9uMS4TD_dmds0_B7K6yBpYnwrTCQLjvfFdnV8yuLb-CXb9k-qATomm03OJvYdncwc1MT-zQac8MQf6BxGfKYrAmSqIIR9R7REfd_PSvSUMFJiD3dHMEPYR7OQmw-NcVrjz70LLsyLT5OVL79sXaCwqQID4Us8lxKFxTxndka4sXxTrMihw_PnwaOMVqe1jfzgn92OQWUIILgy7BHFucP_TeTU8lGxDRfE-PQXYBoVxvk-DqSr2_XAkWB5r1DDAXIq4BdNFMqxqG4ZsOmGF1roqD_uty9hpJ-ex0qLM5M04S6udEJ4lK5avWIxQETJa0aNQEupymjtA2-XX2j00itD8WPdBQPyA5-HjYeExbpGQoExmgHfNOZKWnOp0xxs88kxLYhSxyaBcb2SbN0zaXYWuSgpNPga14K2butwNrJUlIKYwNh9mwfYXOs0MZ6aaoeyHganVbccHZdV9prpH56yLyQBljjgygVoKt_hpTHfmFMeePtA2EUQ0j-jz2HlP2spNv37r--_c0kVJZ3rx1fbSCn9Va7-gsHIEEUQvFpLoYPPBu&box_client_name=box-content-preview&box_client_version=2.48.1" alt="First slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item " style="box-shadow: inset 3px 4px 5px #000 !important;">
                <img class="d-block w-100" id="applegate" src="https://public.boxcloud.com/api/2.0/internal_files/712659573948/versions/757342863948/representations/png_paged_2048x2048/content/1.png?access_token=1!FQaE1Ygcg_2tnoF9ePNlbE07xrS7OhNS_HMOHJju0Eo4WXolNXHYsrppoibjO5rb99-X8oI3CKmEnjTlYHdF4P00vD4iMgygADLSSMChGqRrIld3D-2VjFxckPC5BbmQ-9uMS4TD_dmds0_B7K6yBpYnwrTCQLjvfFdnV8yuLb-CXb9k-qATomm03OJvYdncwc1MT-zQac8MQf6BxGfKYrAmSqIIR9R7REfd_PSvSUMFJiD3dHMEPYR7OQmw-NcVrjz70LLsyLT5OVL79sXaCwqQID4Us8lxKFxTxndka4sXxTrMihw_PnwaOMVqe1jfzgn92OQWUIILgy7BHFucP_TeTU8lGxDRfE-PQXYBoVxvk-DqSr2_XAkWB5r1DDAXIq4BdNFMqxqG4ZsOmGF1roqD_uty9hpJ-ex0qLM5M04S6udEJ4lK5avWIxQETJa0aNQEupymjtA2-XX2j00itD8WPdBQPyA5-HjYeExbpGQoExmgHfNOZKWnOp0xxs88kxLYhSxyaBcb2SbN0zaXYWuSgpNPga14K2butwNrJUlIKYwNh9mwfYXOs0MZ6aaoeyHganVbccHZdV9prpH56yLyQBljjgygVoKt_hpTHfmFMeePtA2EUQ0j-jz2HlP2spNv37r--_c0kVJZ3rx1fbSCn9Va7-gsHIEEUQvFpLoYPPBu&box_client_name=box-content-preview&box_client_version=2.48.1" alt="Second slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://public.boxcloud.com/api/2.0/internal_files/712659573948/versions/757342863948/representations/png_paged_2048x2048/content/1.png?access_token=1!FQaE1Ygcg_2tnoF9ePNlbE07xrS7OhNS_HMOHJju0Eo4WXolNXHYsrppoibjO5rb99-X8oI3CKmEnjTlYHdF4P00vD4iMgygADLSSMChGqRrIld3D-2VjFxckPC5BbmQ-9uMS4TD_dmds0_B7K6yBpYnwrTCQLjvfFdnV8yuLb-CXb9k-qATomm03OJvYdncwc1MT-zQac8MQf6BxGfKYrAmSqIIR9R7REfd_PSvSUMFJiD3dHMEPYR7OQmw-NcVrjz70LLsyLT5OVL79sXaCwqQID4Us8lxKFxTxndka4sXxTrMihw_PnwaOMVqe1jfzgn92OQWUIILgy7BHFucP_TeTU8lGxDRfE-PQXYBoVxvk-DqSr2_XAkWB5r1DDAXIq4BdNFMqxqG4ZsOmGF1roqD_uty9hpJ-ex0qLM5M04S6udEJ4lK5avWIxQETJa0aNQEupymjtA2-XX2j00itD8WPdBQPyA5-HjYeExbpGQoExmgHfNOZKWnOp0xxs88kxLYhSxyaBcb2SbN0zaXYWuSgpNPga14K2butwNrJUlIKYwNh9mwfYXOs0MZ6aaoeyHganVbccHZdV9prpH56yLyQBljjgygVoKt_hpTHfmFMeePtA2EUQ0j-jz2HlP2spNv37r--_c0kVJZ3rx1fbSCn9Va7-gsHIEEUQvFpLoYPPBu&box_client_name=box-content-preview&box_client_version=2.48.1" alt="Third slide">
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!--Content-->
    <div class='container'>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 pl-md-5 pr-md-4">
          <h2>Who We Are</h2>

                    <p>
                 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </p>


      </div>  
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**My attempted solution:**

CSS:

```
/* On mobile, when navbar collapsed, set page container padding to 0vh */
@media (max-width: 769px) {

    .navbar-collapse .page-container{
        padding-top:0vh
    }

}
```

Also tried a javascript solution, trying to add event-listener when navbar is collapsed in order to do something:

```
if ($('#toggle').attr('aria-expanded') == "true") {
  console.log("true")
  }
```

Neither solution is working. What am I doing wrong here? I imagine in JS I could just have an event listener that known when the navbar is collapsed, and when that happens, re-size the page container so there is no padding.  But, maybe there is a simple CSS solution?

Comment: if you add a live example it would be much easier to debug

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky  - added code snippet!

Comment: Hey @DiamondJoe12 are you want to when ever nav bar is expand and collapse slider is move downside or upside accordingly, am i right ?

Comment: @ChintanKotadiya - correct, I want the image carousel (which is the first item in the page container div, to always sit right below the Navbar, when it's expanded , or collapsed.  As it is, there is a bunch of whitespace.  This is because I need to increase the padding of the page container down when the navbar is expanded.. but then the same padding is there when the navbar is collapsed.

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 thanks one more thing i want to corret with you. do you want fix-top bar or it has been scroll with window in mobile and web view.

Comment: @ChintanKotadiya - The idea was to fix the navbar to the top on both mobile and desktop.. that's the intent.. although I'm open to being convinced it's a dumb idea.

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 You have set the fix position of nav bar. which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used to position the element.A fixed element does not leave a gap in the page where it would normally have been located.

Comment: @ChintanKotadiya - it is fixed.  See my code: class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light"

Comment: Great @DiamondJoe12 Also i am posting an answer for another solution if some case that will help.

Comment: @ChintanKotadiya - thanks, but your solution doesn't fix the problem.  When you expand the navbar, it covers the page content (i.e. carousel).  That's why I need to adjust the top-padding on the page-content dynamically, so that when the menu is expanded, the content moves down with it and isn't obscured.  See my original question in the post - in bold.

Comment: I have found the solution and will add an answer when I'm able.  Using bootstrap "stick-top" did the trick: <nav id="navbar" class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">

Answer (score 0):

Just saw that Bootstrap 4 has another option besides fixed-top - it's called "stick-top".

This fixed the issue:

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
```